# DOM doesn't update upon child tags that are appended with JQuery

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I'm trying to dynamically append child riot.js tags depending on the results of an API call. Whenever I try to append these tags using jquery's `.append()` function, the DOM does not update. I tried the following method described on this github thread (which doesn't work for me):

https://github.com/riot/riot/issues/2279

```
var myTag = document.createElement('my-tag')
$('#container').append(myTag)
riot.mount(myTag)
```

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do (code listed below as well): https://jsfiddle.net/7m2z7cus/12/

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/riot/riot/master/riot.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <foo></foo>
    <script>
      riot.tag('bar', '<h1>hello</h1>', '', '', function(opts) { });
      riot.tag('foo', '<div id="bars"></div>', '', '', function(opts) {
        var bar = document.createElement('bar');
        $('#bars').append(bar);
        riot.mount(bar);
      });
      riot.mount('foo');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I expect the `#bars` div to have a `bar` tag appended to it displaying "Hello" on the screen but it's not there. The page is blank. How should I go about dynamically appending nested tags like in the example above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is totally possible and your implementation is really close to working.

The only thing your missing is that the tag `foo` needs to be fully mounted before you can reference DOM nodes inside the tag, i.e. trying to reference `$('#bars')` won't reference anything if `foo` isn't fully mounted.

So, in order to get this to work, you will need to create and append the tag `bar` after `foo` has mounted which is done by utilizing the `'mount'` event
for the tag `foo`.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/riot/riot/master/riot.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <foo></foo>
    <script>
      riot.tag('bar', '<h1>hello</h1>', '', '', function(opts) { });
      riot.tag('foo', '<div id="bars"></div>', '', '', function(opts) {
        this.on('mount', function() {
          // foo has fully mounted. DOM Nodes are accessible inside this callback
          var bar = document.createElement('bar');
          $('#bars').append(bar);
          riot.mount('bar');
        })

      });
      riot.mount('foo');
  </script>
</body>
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ypwwma2s/

Comment: Ahh, that makes a lot of sense. Everything is working now. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No problem. It was an issue that I also ran into when I started using riot.js :)